# Qt GUI Application Wizard in Visual Studio 2017 does not enable the Finish button

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, the Qt GUI Application Wizard does not seem to be able to enable it's Finish button.

- I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community edition.
- I have installed qt5:x64-windows-static using vcpkg.
- I have installed Qt Visual Studio Tools and I believe I have correctly configured it to use my installed Qt

When I try to create a new Qt GUI Application, the Qt GUI Application Wizard is shown. I click through the wizard using Next until I get to the end, however at the end, the Finish button remains disabled.

What have I done wrong?

[image: Qt GUI Application Wizard. I've got to the end and the Finish button is still disabled.]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Qt Visual Studio Tools extension

I get the same result when I try the other Qt Visual Studio Tools project types:

- Qt ActiveQt Server
- Qt Class Library
- Qt Console Application
- Qt Designer Custom Widget

It seems to work with the Qt Empty Application

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution? How did you install qt? I used `vcpkg install`.